# how can i add an opacity color code in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

i am not a coder but i wonder if anyone can help me with this.

is possible to make the below color opacity?  for example how do i add this opacity code: #00ffff; opacity:0.2;

```
/**
             * convert a color name
             * @param string name
             * @return string 
             */
            convert_colour: function (name) {
                
                let result = '#000000';
                
                switch (name) {
                    
                    case 'cyan':
                        result =  '#00ffff';
                        break;
                }
                
                return result;
            },
```

Comment: This is Javascript/css, not PHP.

Comment: yes you are right that how bad i am in coding :(

Answer (score 0):

You just add the value after your variable.

You could add a default opacity in the return for all values.

```
/**
 * convert a color name
 * @param string name
 * @return string 
 */
convert_colour: function (name) {
    
    let result = '#000000;';
    
    switch (name) {
        
        case 'cyan':
            result =  '#00ffff';
            break;
    }
    
    return result. 'opacity:0.2;';
},
```

Or add it in your case

```
/**
 * convert a color name
 * @param string name
 * @return string 
 */
convert_colour: function (name) {
    
    let result = '#000000';
    
    switch (name) {
        
        case 'cyan':
            result =  '#00ffff;opacity:0.2;';
            break;
    }
    
    return result;
},
```

Comment: In your first example, the opacity would be overwritten/removed if it the name is `cyan`.

Comment: thx hype :) but is not working is not making it opacity the color just makes it total transparent even though i change to 0.9, maybe is not possible like that in javascript?

Comment: thx Magnus, for your time but as i said i am not a coder and thought if i add just opcity like that it will work. i don't know what you mean with overwritten/removed if it the name is cyan

Comment: I fixed my first example to define a default opacity value in the return. Before if the name was cyan the result would have been "#00ffff" so no opacity defined.

Answer (score 0):

i got it had to be with RGB to work for me

case 'cyan':
result = 'rgba(0 255, 255, 0.2)';
break;